# SIC about BYTE X and C

Tags: assembly, byte, sic

```
BYTE X'05'
BYTE C'05'
```

what is difference between X and C?

if I want to write object program,how can I make LOC?

Comment: Which assembler is that?

Comment: Looks like [SIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Instructional_Computer) ?

Comment: @PaulR: yup, that's what I thought the title was saying, too.  We don't have tags for every toy assembler, I guess we might as well create them since this probably isn't the first or last SIC or SIC/XE question.

Comment: So it looks like X is a hex indicator and C indicates a constant string?

Comment: I assume `X` is hex and `C` is ASCII character codes, like `db "05"` vs. `db 0x05` in NASM syntax or something.  Or in C like `static char unnamed[] = { 0x05, '0', '5' };` if I'm understanding correctly from the wikipedia example.

Comment: I just learn SIC for two month.I see the program on the book.

Comment: So X is hex and C is ASCII code.If I want  to make LOC I need to  make ASCII to hex to work?